# Display tab content when click the tab menu bootstrap4 alpha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks on the menu tab, I need the respective tab content to open and once the click on the menu tab again the content will close.

I've removed all the active class from both the tab menu and tab content .

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').toggleclass('active');
});

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">ZOOO</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">ABC</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">123</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">EFG</div>
</div>
```

This is fiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qgerfc3/)

Comment: how about a `data-toggle` and a collapse? (As explained here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

Comment: actually tab will enable you to display at the same place but if you use collapse it will show in diffrent way

Comment: Do you mean a tab something like this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h but with the difference that you can close it again?

Comment: As per your example look tab contents are showing in a box at same place but when you got so much collapse menus like tab menus then each collapse contents will be shown in different places unlike tab menu which shows its content in a box

Comment: Ok i understand, but for me your jsFiddle does not work. I can click the tab but no content shows up. Can you look at that because without a working example I can't help you much

Comment: that's my problem sir.I also can't find the reason of not working,Just want first time it will be hidden but when click each menu it will show the respective content and when i click the menu again it will be hidden

Comment: Add `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. The jsfiddle works then

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: Can you send me the whole code of your site and not just the fiddle because the fiddle works for me now, but not your code.

Comment: And btw StackOverflow is asking me to move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: I've answered in chat